# How to run the anonymous function

Tags: c#, asynchronous, anonymous, async-await

These two functions work but my problem is that the anonymous function (the one that receives the `ServiceCheck` as argument) is never called.
What do I have to do to make the `CheckServiceConnection` function return the string so that the anonymous function will run?

```
internal async void CheckServiceConnection()
{
    await _da.CheckServiceConnection((ServiceCheck) =>
    {
        GeneralEventArgs args = new GeneralEventArgs();
        args.GeneralObject = (object)ServiceCheck;
        ServiceConnection(this, args);
    });
}

public Task<string> CheckServiceConnection(Action<string> OnComplited)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

    ws.CheckServiceCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
            tcs.TrySetException(e.Error);
        else if (e.Cancelled)
            tcs.TrySetCanceled();
        else if (e.Result != null)
            tcs.TrySetResult(e.Result);
    };
    try
    {
        ws.CheckServiceAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ws.LogAsync(ex.Message, "DataManager.CheckServiceConnection()");
    }
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

When I write the `CheckServiceConnection` function like that - it is working
(and of course that `CheckServiceConnection` receives no arguments):

```
internal async void CheckServiceConnection()
{
    var ServiceCheck = await _da.CheckServiceConnection();
    GeneralEventArgs args = new GeneralEventArgs();
    args.GeneralObject = (object)ServiceCheck;
    ServiceConnection(this, args);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the parentheses are correct in your first one, where it says `await _da.CheckServiceConnection((ServiceCheck)`?

Comment: Yes, the ServiceCheck is the string that return back to the anonymous function when CheckServiceConnection is done.

Answer (score 2):

Your `CheckServiceConnection` method never calls the `OnComplited` action argument passed to it.  That's why your anonymous function in the first function never gets called.

If you want to pass an anonymous function to `CheckServiceConnection` and have it called, you need to call it.  That is, you add a line like this:

```
OnComplited( "some string" );
```

Comment: That is obvious, but my problem is how do I wrap OnComplited("some string") with tcs.TrySetResult(....)   ?

Answer (score 0):

You're never calling the argument. It's not going to be called automatically.

However, I don't see much of a reason to do this anyway. You're awaiting the method, so why not just do this?

```
internal async void CheckServiceConnection()
{
  var result = await _da.CheckServiceConnection();

  GeneralEventArgs args = new GeneralEventArgs();
  args.GeneralObject = result;
  ServiceConnection(this, args);
}
```

Also, are you sure the `CheckServiceConnection` method shouldn't return `Task`? That's rarely a good idea.

All in all, it seems like you're mixing a lot of different approaches to notifications, asynchronous code etc. Maybe you want to revise your design a bit?

Comment: @user1731254 Elegant for the sake of elegent is usually a bad idea. Try aiming for "simple" instead :)